# jQuery slide effect with a toggle?

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

Hey guys...I am trying to produce an effect where if I click on a button 1 panel slides to the left and another slides into view. And if I click again, the current one slides away and the one from before slides back in like a toggle button.

I have the following code and it works "sort of"...My code when clicked looks ok the first time clicked, but the second time, the panel over laps before the viewing one hides first.

So to simplify what i am looking for is imagine you have 2 divs 400x600 and you're viewing div 1 by default and when the button is clicked, div 1 slides to the left out of view, and div 2 slides in also from the left after div 1 is hidden and when clicked again, div 2 slides to the left and div 1 slides back in also from the left...it toggles..

```
jQuery(".button").click(function() {
    var $lefty = jQuery(".home");
       $lefty.animate({
       left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0}, 

 function() {
    jQuery(".member_home").show();
    var $lefty = jQuery(".member_home");
       $lefty.animate({
       left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0
});

});
    return false;
});
```

If anyone can give me a hand here, it would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're always animating `.home` followed by `.member_home`, when this isn't actually the case all the time.  When `.home` is off-screen, you want to animate `.member-home` off the screen first, and then animate `.home` in.  The effect you're seeing is because you're always animating the `div`s in the same order, no matter which is off-screen.

Here's a function that adds logic that will fix that:

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var $home = $("#home");
    var $memberHome = $("#member-home");
    var $slideOut, $slideIn;

    // See which <divs> should be animated in/out.
    if ($home.position().left < 0) {
        $slideIn = $home;
        $slideOut = $memberHome;
    }
    else {
        $slideIn = $memberHome;
        $slideOut = $home;
    }

    $slideOut.animate({
        left: "-" + $slideOut.width() + "px"
    }, function() {
        $slideIn.animate({ left: "0px" });
    });
}
```

And then call that function from your button click handler:

```
$("button").bind("click", function() {
    toggleDivs();
});
```

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/qSvDz/.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct!  Thank you for taking the time to show me this example..most appreciated.  I am new to JS, may I ask why you can declare variables like in PHP $home?  Why do you need the dollar sign? Is var $home equal to var home?

Comment: @Rick: Using the dollar sign is just a convention I use to make it clear that that variable contains a jQuery result.  You don't need the dollar sign, I suppose it's just habit after working on projects with lots of variables, it's useful to be able to glance at a variable and tell that it's got a jQuery result in it.

Comment: I see, thanks for that explanation but when I see that, I immediately think of PHP variables...hehe..

Answer (score 0):

Make the sliding in of the second panel a callback function. Then it won't slide in until the first panel has been hidden.
**edit**

```
jQuery(".button").click(function() {
    var $lefty = jQuery(".home");
       $lefty.animate({
       left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0}, 

 function() {
    jQuery(".member_home").show(400,function() {
        var $lefty = jQuery(".member_home");
           $lefty.animate({
           left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0
    });
});

});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That didn't work and did the same thing as what I had before.  Please note that the first click works..panel 1 slides off and panel 2 slides in. But it is the second click that doesn't behave.  Second click the hidden panel comes out first and then the currently viewing panel (panel 2) slides off thus causing an overlap..